# which one is best for build mobile application. IONIC Framework, Onsen Framework, IBM Worklight, Snecha or other

Tags: jquery-mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I am little confused which one is best for build hybrid mobile application.
IONIC Framework, Onsen Framework,  IBM Worklight, Sencha or other. I am familiar with javascript, css, and angular.js

Comment: ionic is best if you know angular

Answer (score 4):

There is no "better" framework. They all have their own strength and weakness.

The only things that matter for me when I want to start a new project with a new technology are:

- Is it mature enough to be used in production?
- Is it still in developpment?
- Is it well documented?
- Is the community active?
- Is it hard to use?

I'm using Onsen UI And Ionic and for what I can tell, both are doing the job, are easy to learn once you know how to use Angular.

**Ionic:**

- Big community and support
- Lots of tool to make your developpment easier
- Plugins and themes available
- Growing project

**Onsen UI**

- Can be used with multiple framework
- Good Documentation
- Easy Router implementation
- Small community